# CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont does not register the family name

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

For reasons related to licensing, I have to decrypt a font file and load it into memory then then register it instead of reading directly from a URL. For this I have to use `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`.

The problematic part comes when I try to use `[NSFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:21.0]` where it will only accept the font's PostScript name (i.e. ("OpenSans or OpenSans-Bold for the bold weight) and won't work the family name "Open Sans".

If a font is registered using `ATSApplicationFontsPath`in the info.plist file or using `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURLs` then I am able to use the font's family name. But I can't do it this way.

("Open Sans" is used here as an example)

Here's the relevant code I'm using to register the font.

```c
NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"OpenSans-Regular" ofType:@"ttf" inDirectory:@"Fonts"];
NSData *fontData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fontPath];

CGDataProviderRef fontProviderRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)fontData);
CGFontRef fontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontProviderRef);
CFErrorRef error;

if (! CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &error)) {

    CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
    NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
    CFRelease(errorDescription);
}

CFRelease(fontRef);
CFRelease(fontProviderRef);
```

Is there a way to make the font family name available to NSFont with `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`?

(Using Xcode 5 and targeting Mac OS X >= 10.8)

Comment: Have you tried using a font descriptor for creating your font with the family name?

Comment: @LeoNatan have not tried yet, will do.

Comment: Let me know if it works so I can add an answer.

Comment: @LeoNatan unfortunately descriptors suffer from the same issue. The resultant NSFont object doesn't respond to having a bold trait using convertFont toHaveTrait.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? this is plaguing me too.

Comment: @DanielWabyick unfortunately not

Answer (score 7):

**update:**

Ok, to verify that the family name comes from the font file itself: I tried this with a font I have... GillSansMTStd-Light. I changed the family name in the font file to "Gill Sans Std Mt Light", and subsequently I could use `[ NSFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans MT Std Light" size:10.0 ]`.

fontforge font info panel:

[image]

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

---

I looked through all the combinations of CT/NS font and font manager APIs I could think of. Seems there is no API to associate a family name with a font--I think this data comes from the font file itself.

I guess there needs to be a (Mac) font family and font subfamily entry in the font name table. (cf. https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM06/Chap6name.html)

I have used [FontForge](http://www.fontforge.org) to edit font files in the past--maybe that can help you? Seems you can install it via homebrew.

Finally, I think there's an easier way to add a font to the `CTFontManager`. I changed your code to:

```
// register the font:
NSURL * url = [[ NSBundle mainBundle ] URLForResource:@"OpenSans-Regular" withExtension:@"ttf" ] ;
assert( url ) ;

CFErrorRef error = 0 ;
bool ok = CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL( (__bridge CFURLRef)url, kCTFontManagerScopeProcess, &error ) ;
assert( ok && !error ) ;

// make sure it's registered (using PS name): 
CTFontRef f = CTFontCreateWithName( CFSTR( "OpenSans-Regular" ), 10.0, NULL ) ;
assert( f ) ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while this works for loading from URLs, it doesn't work for my specific case (and requirement) of loading fonts from memory using NSData.

Comment: oh, was basing it on your code which loads the data from a path in your bundle. I now see you need to decrypt the font file. That must be the worlds most expensive font for it to require encryption in your bundle.

Comment: that's usually the case with proprietary fonts. There are specific clauses for usage with apps.

Comment: the font files I have contain the correct family names and meta data, so editing will not help. It looks like I have to use two NSFont objects, one for regular and one for bold instead of traits.

Comment: That seems like a separate question. I thought you wanted to be able to refer to fonts by their family name not their PS name?